# AttributeError: 'Web_scraping' object has no attribute '_Web_scraping__headless'

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am having this attributeError AttributeError: 'Web_scraping' object has no attribute '_Web_scraping__headless'

```
import time
import os
from scraping.browser_manager import constants as const
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from scraping.browser_manager.automate_browser import Browser_bot

class Web_scraping():
    
    def __init__(self):

        # self.scraper instance
        self.scraper = Browser_bot(headless=self.__headless)

    def accept_cookies(self):
        cookies = self.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
           '.sui-TcfFirstLayer-buttons > button:nth-child(2)'
        )
        time.sleep(5)
        cookies.click()
```

this is the run.py function

```
from scraping.scraper import Web_scraping

try:

    with Web_scraping() as bot:
         bot.accept_cookies()
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it should be:

```
class WebScraping:
```

instead of:

```
class Web_scraping():
```

(Parenthesis are redundant and [PEP 8's style guide for classes' names](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#class-names) recommends you to use CamelCaseNames)

Anyway I wouldn't use the `scraping` module at all (I don't get why you want to use it tbh) and do something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


class WebScraping:
    def __init__(self):
        options = FirefoxOptions()
        # options.add_argument("--headless")
        self.scraper = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
        self.scraper.get("https://www.google.com/")

    def accept_cookies(self):
        cookies = WebDriverWait(self.scraper, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='QS5gu sy4vM']"))).click()


x = WebScraping()
x.accept_cookies()
```

(Note that I used [explicit waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) instead of the worse `time.sleep()`)

Comment: Change that dynamic xpath it looks fragile.

Comment: It is just a random example, he wasn't even trying to scrape that page!

Comment: I am calling the modules scraping scraper because there I have the automate class for the browser.